# How Can You Turn a Low Poly Game Model Into a High Poly Model for a Cinematic?

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, edit-mode, conversion

I have extracted a couple models from Overwatch, and they are very low poly. My goal is to make the models look cinematic worthy [I read in this as to how Blizzard made them look good for cinematics.](http://www.behindthecinematic.com/people/jeff-chamberlain/) So what I have to do is change the mesh to include more detail. Here is a high poly version of Soldier 76:[image: High Poly Soldier 76][image: Here is the comparison.] How can I turn the low poly version of the mesh into a detailed high poly version for a cinematic. I know about the subdivision surface modifier, but that's not what I am going for. Here is the Blend file for Soldier 76 [image], the faces are triangulated, but quadralating them works if I have to add a Subdivision Surface modifier. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This is very achievable in Blender. Blender has been a professional-grade design tool for some time; its interface and the entrenchment of Autodesk in the industry is what has kept it from gaining traction in the industry, although that has been changing recently. Blender will allow you to make very sophisticated shaders and materials, and has a sculpting feature that is sufficient or better. Its renderers (Cycles and Eevee) can take advantage of your GPU to dramatically boost efficiency. Finally, even though the newest version is just coming out, the most jarring changes are to the UI and..

Comment: ...and the software is extremely well-documented.

I'll also mention that your question is asking for (more or less) an opinion and moderators are extremely crusty about those because they see StackExchange as a knowledge repository, not a debate forum. This question may get deleted. Try blogs or forums if you want advice like this next time

Comment: Re moderation. The question lends to a yes/no answer. Elaborating on yes, would be pretty broad and opinion based.

Comment: Thank You for your feedback, I edited my question.